# Linear algebra singularity proof

Tags: linear-algebra

problem: A (square) matrix is singular if there exists a vector v ≠ such that AV = 0. In this case, the system Ax=b has no solution or infinitely many solutions.

I've been struggling with doing the proof for this problem and can someone show me an example?

Also, I can seem to find the property that allows us to do this:

Thank you

Comment: if you have a solution how can you construct another one?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbf x$ be a solution to $A\mathbf x = b$ and $A\mathbf v = 0.$

Then $A(\mathbf x+\lambda \mathbf v) = b $ for all $\lambda\in \mathbb R$